# Selectively replace specific nested delimiters (brackets) in strings, while respecting nesting

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pyparsing

I have many strings where I'm trying to selectively replace all instances of `f[--whatever--]` with `f.__getitem__(--whatever--, x=x)`. 
This is the last option left to me to patch some old complicated code using `eval` calls that I'm unfortunately stuck with. 
It's easy to replace the `f[`, but it's hard to know whether instances of `]` are associated with this pattern or some other 
miscellaneous patterns like lists `[--whatever--]` or indexing `.loc[--whatever--].` There are no isolated cases of `]` that are not part of a full `[]` in my strings.

My latest attempt at a solution uses regex:
1) sub ([^f])[(.+?)] with \1openbracket\2closebracket to preserve [] that isn't part of f[]
2) the remaining []
3) sub back openbracket & closebracket with []

The problem is that this doesn't handle many nested cases like the example below. I'm looking for a more comprehensive solution to establish whether a given `]` is associated with `f[]` or some other structure. Is there a way to do this with `pyparsing` or some other module?

Example

```
f[r@ndom t3xt] + [some r@ndom t3xt] + [f[more r@ndom t3xt] / f[more t3xt]] + [f[f[more t3xt] + 3]]
```

should become

```
f.__getitem__(r@ndom t3xt, x=x) + [some r@ndom t3xt] + [f.__getitem__(more r@ndom t3xt, x=x) / f.__getitem__(more t3xt, x=x)] + [f.__getitem__(f.__getitem__(more t3xt) + 3)]
```

Comment: Try this [`f\[([^\]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/KdPP4q/1/)

Comment: Thanks @CodeManiac but this still misses some nested cases. I added to my example text - see [f[f[more t3xt] + 3]]

Comment: Well in such cases you need a recursive way to do it, as a suggestion you can make the RegEx greedy and inside you call back you can again check if it has any nested pattern recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using Regex:

```
import re

string1 = "f[r@ndom t3xt] + [some r@ndom t3xt] + 3[f2[more r@ndom t3xt] / f[more t3xt]] + [f[f[more t3xt] + 3]]"
string3 = '''f[text([0,[1,2],3, x["text3"]])]'''


def get_repl(match):
    if match.groups()[-1]:
        # replace nested [ and ]  with special characters
        return match.groups()[-1].replace('[', '##1##').replace(']', '##2##')
    else:
        return '{}.__getitem__({}, x=x)'.format(*match.groups()[:-1])

def place_by_getitem(string):
    pattern = '(?<!\w)(f)\[([^\[]+?)\]|(\[[^\[]+?\])'
    while re.search(pattern, string):
        string = re.sub(pattern, get_repl, string)

    return string.replace('##1##', '[').replace('##2##', ']')


print(place_by_getitem(string1))
print(place_by_getitem(string3))
```

Output:

```
f.__getitem__(r@ndom t3xt, x=x) + [some r@ndom t3xt] + 3[f2.__getitem__(more r@ndom t3xt, x=x) / f.__getitem__(more t3xt, x=x)] + [f.__getitem__(f.__getitem__(more t3xt, x=x) + 3, x=x)]
f.__getitem__(text([0,[1,2],3, x.__getitem__("text3", x=x)]), x=x)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as well for the cases I've tried and seems faster  
  
```%timeit -n 3 f_expr.transformString(string1) # pyparsing  
9.91 ms ± 2.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 3 loops each)
%timeit -n 3 place_by_getitem(string1) # regex
The slowest run took 4.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
28.7 µs ± 20.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 3 loops each)```

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, can you explain what is the problem with this solution?

Comment: I'm using Regex it should be faster.

Comment: On more testing, this method fails in cases with quotes

`string3 = '''f["text([0,1,2,3])"]'''`  
`place_by_getitem(string3) # regex`  
`'f["text([0,1,2,3])"]'`  
`f_expr.transformString(string3) # pyparsing`  
`'f.__getitem__("text([0,1,2,3])", x=x)'`

Comment: I think I found a solution for this problem, this has an advantage over the accepted answer because it accepts more letters not just f could be `f2, x, fx a valid identifier in ASCII letter starting with letter` and match faster,  check my edits

Comment: I checked your edits. I only want to match `f[..]`, not `f2[...]` etc.  More specifically, I want to match, in regex syntax: `(?<!\w)f\[.+\]`.  I agree with you regex would have an advantage because of speed, if it's possible

Comment: So just :  `pattern = '(f)\[([^\[]+?)\]|(\[[^\[]+?\])'` will do the job, Hope this is what you needed, I loved your question and I wanted to find a solution with Regex if there is, I think it should work for you

Comment: Please add that to your answer (either replace or at the end for my specific case) and I will accept it. Thanks for spending time to find a creative solution! I tried across my 500 examples and it yields the same result but is on average 150x faster than using pyparsing, likely benefiting from re's C optimzations

Comment: Yes I really wanted to know if it work for you, I'm working on my skills in Regex and your question was very challenging. glade I helped you thanks

Comment: FYI I ended up using `pattern = '(?<!\w)(f)\[([^\[]+?)\]|(\[[^\[]+?\])'` which also ignores `notf[sometext]` which is better for my use case

Answer (score 1):

Nested []'s make this a non-trivial problem. pyparsing has a "crutch" expression method called `nestedExpr` that makes it easy to match nested delimiters like ()'s and []'s. pyparsing also has the transformString method, for converting as-parsed data into a different form. We can use a parse-time callback (or "parse action") to repeatedly convert any nested `f[zzz]` terms until all have been transformed:

```
import pyparsing as pp

fname = pp.Keyword('f')
index_expr = pp.nestedExpr('[', ']')
# nestedExpr will give a nested list by default, we just want the original raw text
f_expr = fname + pp.originalTextFor(index_expr)("index_expr")

# define a parse action to convert the f[aaa] format to f._getitem__(aaa, x=x)
def convert_to_getitem(t):
    # get the contents of the index_expr, minus the leading and trailing []'s
    index_expr = t.index_expr[1:-1]

    # repeatedly call transform string to get further nested f[] expressions, until 
    # transformString stops returning a modified string
    while True:
        transformed = f_expr.transformString(index_expr)
        if transformed == index_expr:
            break
        index_expr = transformed

    # reformat to use getitem
    return "f.__getitem__({}, x=x)".format(transformed)

# add the parse action to f_expr
f_expr.addParseAction(convert_to_getitem)


# use transformString to convert the input string with nested expressions
sample = "f[r@ndom t3xt] + [some r@ndom t3xt] + [f[more r@ndom t3xt] / f[more t3xt]] + [f[f[more t3xt] + 3]]"
print(f_expr.transformString(sample))
```

Prints:

```
f.__getitem__(r@ndom t3xt, x=x) + [some r@ndom t3xt] + [f.__getitem__(more r@ndom t3xt, x=x) / f.__getitem__(more t3xt, x=x)] + [f.__getitem__(f.__getitem__(more t3xt, x=x) + 3, x=x)]
```

This should also handle '[]'s that might occur in quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
f\[([^]]*)\]
```

and a `re.sub` with,

```
f.__getitem__($1, x=x)
```

might simply work.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"f\[([^]]*)\]"

string = """
f[r@ndom t3xt] + [some r@ndom t3xt] + [f[more r@ndom t3xt] / f[more t3xt]]
f[] + [] + [f[] / f[]]

"""

subst = "f.__getitem__($1, x=x)"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, string))
```

#### Output

```
f.__getitem__($1, x=x) + [some r@ndom t3xt] + [f.__getitem__($1, x=x) / f.__getitem__($1, x=x)]
f.__getitem__($1, x=x) + [] + [f.__getitem__($1, x=x) / f.__getitem__($1, x=x)]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/NHaKgl/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/NHaKgl/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---